Morphing between circles
In an algorithm there is one property needed that is a bit unintuitive. For simplicity, we say there is a circle $K_1$ centered at the origin with radius $r_1>0$. Define
$$f_1(X):=\frac{x^2+y^2}{r_1^2}$$
for $X=(x,y)\in R^2$. Therefore, $K_1:=\{X\in R^2:f_1(X)\leq 1\}$.
Another circle $K_2$ of radius $r_2>0$ is located at $M=(m,0)$, for some $m>0$. Similarly one defines
$$f_2(X):=\frac{(x-m)^2+y^2}{r_2^2}$$
Again, $K_2=\{X\in R^2:f_2(X)\leq 1\}$.
Now let's mix things up: I want to prove that for any $\lambda\in[0,1]$, the inequality
$$f_\lambda(X):=(1-\lambda)f_1(X)+\lambda f_2(X)\leq 1$$
defines a circle (it is clear for $\lambda\in\{0,1\}$). We may assume that the two circles have at least one point in common, i.e. $m\leq r_1+r_2$.
I did have the idea to rewrite the expression as
$$f_\lambda(X)=f_1(X)\left(1+\lambda\left(\frac{r_1^2}{r_2^2}-1\right)\right)+\lambda\frac{m\,(m-2x)}{r_2^2}.$$
Brute force "completing the square" does the job of proving that the set $\{X\in R^2:f_\lambda(X)\leq 1\}$ is a circle. But maybe there is an intuitive understanding from above formula?


"An intuitive understanding" of the construction: A circle in
the Euclidean plane (equipped with a Cartesian frame) is uniquely
defined by an equation
$$\label{eq:1}
x^2 +y^2 -2ax -2by +c = 0.\tag{$\star$}
$$
It is the circle with center $(a, b)$ and radius $\sqrt{a^2 +b^2 -c}$.
So such a circle is proper (i.e. a real circle) if and only if
$a^2 +b^2 -c > 0$.  When $a^2 +b^2 -c = 0$, the circle is reduced to a
point and, in the remaining case, it is an imaginary circle.

What we need to understand is that in this way $\mathbb{R}^3$ (with
coordinates $(a, b, c)$) is a natural parameter space for the circles
in the Euclidean plane.  The real circles correspond to points
outside the elliptic paraboloid $a^2 +b^2 -c = 0$.

If we take two circles defined by the points $(a, b, c)$ and
$(a', b', c')$, the line defined by the two points in $\mathbb{R}^3$
represents a pencil of circles, each circle of the pencil being
defined by a point
$$
(1 -\lambda)(a, b, c) +\lambda(a', b', c'),
$$
with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.  The equation of the corresponding circle
becomes
[
\begin{split}
  0
  &= (1 -\lambda)[x^2 +y^2 -2ax -2by +c]
  +\lambda[x^2 +y^2 -2a'x -2b'y +c'] \\
  &= x^2 +y^2 -2((1 -\lambda)a +\lambda a')x
  -2((1 -\lambda)b +\lambda b')x +((1 -\lambda)c +\lambda c').
\end{split}
]

Remark. Such a pencil is easier to understand geometrically
(i.e. in the plane) when the two circles have a point in common.  The
point of intersection comes either together with a second different
point of intersection, or is a point of intersection with multiplicity
$2$ (the two circles are tangent at the intersection point).  Taking
the mediator of the two intersection points, the pencil consists of
all the circles with centers on the mediator and passing through the
two intersection points.
Remark. It is a useful exercise to show that the two circles
intersect in two distinct points if and only if the line (in the
parameter space) does not intersect the paraboloid.  The other
configurations in $\mathbb{R}^3$ should also be considered.

Coming back to your situation, I shall use $r$ for $r_1$ and $R$
for $r_2$.  So we have the equations of two circles,
$$
x^2 + y^2 - r^2 = 0
$$
and
$$
(x -m)^2 + y^2 - R^2 = 0.
$$
They correspond in the parameter space to the points $(0, 0, -r^2)$
and $(m, 0, -R^2)$.  The affine combination of the two equations
(written like that) defines a pencil of circles; the centers and
radii of the circles in the pencil are easy to compute (see 2)).

In the form appearing in the question, the computations become more
involved.  But all we need to see is that the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ are eventually equal and non zero (at least with the restriction $\lambda \in [0, 1]$).  Thus, dividing by this common coefficient, we
arrive at the equation of a circle in the form \eqref{eq:1}, and, "by brute force" obtain its center and radius.
